# Using es6 classes in html script tag

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack-2

I want to start writing my JS code in ES6's classes.

I'm making modules and transcript them to es5 with `webpack 2`.

But how to use them in HTML??

```
<script>
var test=new Test();//Test not defined
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the fact that you don't need to do this when writing a nice modular app. Everything that needs to be used outside bundled app should be exposed to `window`.

Comment: Can You give me link to some tutorial or good practices?

Comment: As for modules themselves, you can check [this write-up](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html). The purpose of modules is to encapsulate everything and don't pollute global scope - exactly the opposite from how you're trying to use them. If you need to do `var test=new Test();`, do this inside generated JS and load it with `<script src=...>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to write within script tags if you've already got half on your code within ES6? Just write the code that you're trying to write in the `script` tag in another module.

See https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&code=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter(%22world%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0D%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(greeter.greet())%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B

Comment: I see - thanks for guidence

Comment: And can You please tell me how to pass params to classes? As html tag's attributes?

Comment: It might be worth looking at some MVVM framework for binding back to the DOM - http://knockoutjs.com/